# Read Csv file with LineFeeds within its fields

Tags: vb.net, csv, vb.net-2010

I have this code to read a csv file :

```
Dim strLineValue As String
Using sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText("FilePath")

strLineValue = sr.ReadLine
      Do While strLineValue IsNot Nothing
          strLineValue = sr.ReadLine
           n += 1
      Loop
End Using
```

My problem is that I come across a csv file that the lines is like this:

```
 "Text1 LF LF text2","text3",text4,text5, , , , ,LF 
 "Text6 LF LF text8","text9",text10,text11, , , , ,LF
```

where LF is Line Feed.

So I get something like this which is wrong

```
Text1

text2    text3    text4    text5
Text6

text8    text9    text10   text11
```

Any ideas how I can overcome this wrong behaviour of my code in this type of files

PS. 1.If I open the csv file in excel it recognises the lines properly , it just have a multiline first cell
2. I am thinking that maybe the first 2 LF are just LF and the LF that I have in the end of each line are LF and CR but how I can see the difference (I opened the csv file in the Word to see the characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some fields that are enclosed in double-quotes - `"`.  In CSV files, that usually indicates that you're supposed to take the whole field and not parse it.

This is really easy to do with the [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FielIO.TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class.  Here's an example:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Dim parser As TextFieldParser = New TextFieldParser("TestFile.txt")

parser.Delimiters = New String() {","}
parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True

While Not parser.EndOfData

    Dim fields As String() = parser.ReadFields()

End While
```

This will preserve the line feeds in the quoted fields:

```
"Text1 LF LF text2" "text3" "text"4 "text5" blank blank blank blank blank
```

Comment: The problem is that not all the data are in quotes

Comment: @Nianios - that doesn't matter.  `TextFieldParser` will handle lines that have mixed fields - quoted and non-quoted - just fine.  The code sample I posted above was run on your sample input, and the output I posted is the elements of the array for the first line after reading the fields.

Comment: For me, it doesn't work when the fields are not enclosed in "" :-( It will treat the LF as Line Ending and everything get's messed up

Answer (score 0):

I would try;

```
strLineValue = strLineValue.replace(vblf,"")
```

And see it indeed the end of the line has a CR...

You can see the difference in a HEX editor, a lf = 10 and a cr=13

```
chr(10) & chr(13) = vbcrlf
```

Comment: This is a workable solution, but if there is a reason the data is multi-line in a cell OP may want to preserve the formatting.

Comment: You were right. Is 0A for LF and 0A 0D for LFCR. So I have two LF and then a LFCR.
So how I can overcome this in code.Your code is not working strLineValue is null

Comment: @Tim : He doesn't care (obviously we need a space instead of LF)