# Best way to read BIG text files with crlf line delimiter

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, readline

I have a very large comma delimited text file.  Each field is, as stated, delimited by a comma and surrounded by quotes (all strings).  The problem is that some of the fields contain a CR for multiple lines within that field.   So when I do a ReadLine it stops at that CR.  It would be nice if I can tell it to ONLY stop at CRLF combinations.

Does anyone have any snappy method to do this?  The files can be very very large.

Comment: Check this [MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/07f3fbab-53cc-4744-9eca-758b61c2f44d/streamreader-readline-new-and-improved-fixed-single-crlf?forum=netfxbcl).

Comment: please provide your code (snippet)!  Using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser is a big help from my experience!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read Csv file with LineFeeds within its fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206487/read-csv-file-with-linefeeds-within-its-fields)

Comment: How big is "very very large"?  Are we talking 10's of MBytes, 100's of MBytes, 100's of TBytes?  Some idea of expected size, or, better yet, maximum size would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want specific `ReadLine`, why not implement it?

```
  public static class MyFileReader {
    public static IEnumerable<String> ReadLineCRLF(String path) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

      Char prior = '\0';
      Char current = '\0';

      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path)) {
        int v = reader.Read();

        if (v < 0) {
          if (prior == '\r')
            sb.Append(prior);

          yield return sb.ToString();

          yield break;
        }

        prior = current;
        current = (Char) v;

        if ((current == '\n') && (prior == '\r')) {
          yield return sb.ToString();

          sb.Clear();
        }
        else if (current == '\r') {
          if (prior == '\r')
            sb.Append(prior);
        }
        else
          sb.Append(current);
      }
    }
  }
```

Then use it

```
  var lines = MyFileReader
    .ReadLineCRLF(@"C:\MyData.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using

```
string line = File.ReadAllText("input.txt"); // Read the text in one line
```

Then split it on carriage return/line feed like this:

```
var split = line.Split('\n'); // I'm not really sure it's \n you'll need, but it's something!
```

and then processing like by line in a loop

```
foreach(var line in split) { ... }
```

Comment: I tried this:

Regex splitter = new Regex("\r\n");
string[] AllLines = splitter.Split(iFile.ReadToEnd());

Somewhat what you're referring to but splitting on CRLF but I still get the occasional split on a CR alone.  Very odd.