# Remove extra comma in raw row read from csv file

Tags: c#, vb.net, csv

I am developing a VB.Net code and I am reading raw rows from csv files for further processing. This is example of the csv content:

```
I Slewrate Check    3   1   1   IDAC Filter 5uS, OSC dmy 3200pF 0.000005
I Slewrate Check    3   2   1   IDAC Filter 50uS, OSC dmy 3200pF    0.0001
I Slewrate Check    3   3   1   IDAC Filter 200uS, OSC dmy 3200pF   0.00035
I test: 1 mA    18  1   1     -1.15 mA Output   -0.001150366
I test: 1 mA    18  1   2     -1.15 mA Meas. HR ADC -0.001150243
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

This is a snip of my way of reading the csv content:

```
For Each rawRows As String In File.ReadLines(diNext.FullName)
                        newList.Clear()
                        processList = rawRows.Split(",")
                        For Each item As String In processList
                            newList.Add(item)
                            'Do something here to save
                        Next
```

So, the newList will have the 5 rows as:

```
1: I Slewrate Check,    3,  1,  1,  IDAC Filter 5uS, OSC dmy 3200pF,    0.000005
2: I Slewrate Check,    3,  2,  1,  IDAC Filter 50uS, OSC dmy 3200pF,   0.0001
3: I Slewrate Check,    3,  3,  1,  IDAC Filter 200uS, OSC dmy 3200pF,  0.00035
4: I test: 1 mA,    18, 1,  1,    -1.15 mA Output,  -0.001150366
5: I test: 1 mA,    18, 1,  2,    -1.15 mA Meas. HR ADC,    -0.001150243
```

The first 3 rows has the extra comma in `IDAC Filter 5uS, OSC dmy 3200pF` which I don't want. Bare in mind that this is just a sample of my csv and the extra comma can occur **at any cell value, not only at the spot shown by the image**. How do I solve this. Any solution in VB.Net or even C# will help me a lot. I am tagging C# here and for god sake, **please don't remove the C# tag...**

In Notepad:
[image]

Comment: Why are you processing the CSV like that and not using `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`?

Comment: Please show us the csv file as rendered in a text editor, not Excel. Excel will never give you a true representation of what the data looks like, since it performs a transform to put it into cells. Using a text editor will show yo whether or not the csv is correctly formatted ,e.g. whether or not the values have delimiters around them when the value contains a comma.

Comment: @Hari So is it that you want to get rid of the extra cell, or that you want the combined values as a single cell? The class I mentioned in my initial comment should handle _quoted_ commas.

Comment: @DeanOC just edited

Comment: @Hari please can you open the CSV using Notepad and copy the raw contents into your question?

Comment: Hope that this will clear my question. Sorry for the bad way of asking just now

Comment: @john, edited the content of csv by opening it in notepad and I want the combined values as a single cell

Comment: If they're not quoted there's no way to do it accurately. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @John, so there are no known ways to solve this?

Comment: OK take these two lines: `John,Baker,29,Engineer` and `John,29,Engineer`. You expect the latter format. How does your software determine that it should be "John,Baker" in one cell as opposed to "Baker,29" or "29,Engineer"?

Comment: @john That is what I am looking for. Haven't managed to find an answer to this. Thanks a lot for your concern man. Have a nice day

Comment: The point I made with my answer is that Baker is a surname, so the columns could be `FirstName,LastName` or it could be an occupation (someone who works in a bakery), so even intelligent software with lists of valid entries might fall down with such an example. It really comes down to your own data and I don't think you'll find an "off the shelf" solution.

Comment: When you open the file in notepad , do you see contents comma separated or Tab separated?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it is tab separated. If you see in my question, in the very beginning I had attached how it looks in notepad

Comment: Did you try spliting by tab character in code? That would give you the result you want.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya just tried that, it returns a my processList as a variable of single string as  "I Slewrate Check,3,1,1,IDAC Filter 5uS, OSC dmy 3200pF,0.000005" without the tab

Comment: @Hari then you did not open it with notepad. I have no idea what you're opening the file with, but if you don't see the commas then it isn't notepad. Could you also include a screenshot of the software you're opening it with?

Comment: @john, look at my edit

Comment: You must have your files confused. I don't see how you can get a single string with commas and see it with tabs in Notepad.

Comment: @john I don't get you

Comment: OK Answer me this: How can you see a file's rows separated by tabs in Notepad, but when you read the line into VB see it separated by commas? Short of some kind of weird unicode issue, you can't. Most logical reason: You have two different but similar files.

Comment: @john sincerely no idea

Comment: Perhaps you should find that out.

Comment: @Hari Can you share  the code which splits the string by tab character?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya `processedList = rawRows.Split(vbTab)`

Comment: @john I made a mistake previously, I copied a portion of the csv file and paste it into notepad. Now, I had opened it in notepad and edited the screenshot. Sorry, my bad

Comment: @Hari Now I see that the areas with extra commas are quoted, meaning `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` would absolutely be able to understand these rows and it is your best option. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18206856/3181933) for an example of how to use it.

Comment: @john Thanks a lot man... It works after a day of struggle... Will pose an answer soon

Comment: Tag me when you do and I'll upvote it :) I'm glad we got it sorted out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a lot to @john....

This is my new function using `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`

```
Dim parser As TextFieldParser = New TextFieldParser(diNext.FullName)
parser.Delimiters = New String() {","}
parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
While Not parser.EndOfData
    Try
       Dim fields As String() = parser.ReadFields()
       'Do my processing from here... yahoooo....
    Catch ex As Exception                                
       'Log problem                               
    End Try
End While
```

Comment: @john, I just saw that some of the lines has an extra double quote like `"EquipDesc[14]","SMU Scanner"Program","PV1500"` It throws the `MalFormedLine` exception. Any idea TextFieldParser can handle this?

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix that. Do you have any control over the source of the CSV file? RFC4180 states that double quotes within a field should be escaped (so `"hello "Hari""` would become `"hello ""Hari"""""`)

Comment: @john I have no control on the csv file